# link on certain position of an image background which is responsive

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, image, responsive-design

I've got a task to do and I'm not able to find a solution or direction in which to target.

**Task**

This task needs some links positioned in a image full background. This image has some products inside it and the links need to be on top of these products, taking into consideration that the screen can be wider or not so the image background could stretch and therefore the position of the links would also have to adapt. Any idea how to do this?

**Tryout**

I tried already the `<map>` and `<area>` tags but the compatibility with tablets can be tricky. Also a great issue is that I can specify its position but I cannot place any image or CSS on these elements. Maybe the solution is with jquery? Any ideas?

**HTML**

```
<div class="hotspots-image">
    <img class="image" src="IMAGE" class="imagemap"/>

    <a class="hotspot" href="#">
        <span class="hotspot-icon">O</span>
    </a>
    <a class="hotspot" href="#">
        <span class="hotspot-icon">O</span>
    </a>
</div>
```

So the hotspot is the links which I suppose would be positioned absolute and in a certain position. Maybe you have other inputs or directions to follow?

Thanks in advance!!!!

**Fiddle:**

http://jsfiddle.net/uDCuB/

Comment: Why would you do it like this? Just cut the image up into manageable pieces. Also setup a JSFiddle so we can see the problem.

Comment: @Ruddy `responsive` is the keyword here....cutting wont really solve the purpose!! :)

Comment: are you able to produce the case? [give us on Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: @Daniel : plz add an image or a fiddle to give us a brief about what you have in mind!! :)

Comment: @NoobEditor I don't know. From what the OP is saying it doesn't make much sense. I would like a demo of this.

Comment: @Ruddy : second that..fiddle is needed for clarity!! :D

Comment: @NoobEditor What I got from his question: They are saying with 1 background with products on it and they want links that move with the background to stay in place on the products? That's what I got from it, it makes no sense. You would just have the products as separate images.

Comment: @NoobEditor The images are already taken. So the products in the images cannot be separated into separated images. The links have to be placed in a certain position of the image. I will create a jsfiddle for the rest...

Comment: @DanielRamirez-Escudero :fiddle is the best idea right now!! :)

Comment: Added already jsfiddle :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One possible solution:

1. Responsive image should be styled as `width: 100%; height: auto;`
2. Calculate the hotspots position in percentages instead of pixels**
3. Use absolute-relative positioning

[Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/salman/mGAX7/)

Having said that, if you have an image and an image map, you can use jQuery to:

1. Wrap the image in a relative positioned container
2. Create absolutely positioned links by parsing `area` tags in image map
3. Discard `usemap` attribute and the `<map>` tag
4. Recalculate position on window resize

** For example:

- If your image is 1000px wide and 200px tall
- Hotspot coordinates are (50,50) - (100,100)
- For image maps this maps to (5%,25%) - (10%,50%)
- For absolute positioning this maps to left: 5%, top: 25%, width: 5%, height: 25%

Answer (score 1):

2 possibilities:

1. Cut the image into the smaller images on which you can use "click" event. Works only if you have control on the background image.
2. You have to use dynamically generated image map. You know your image size and offsets of the products on the image. You can detect the screen size. Appropriately calculate the offsets of the products and generate an image map dynamically.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I cannot cut the images into smaller images as the background of the picture cannot be separated. I will search how to use dynamically generated image map.