# Make certain areas of banner image clickable

Tags: html, css, image, hyperlink

I'm making a new website and on the homepage is a big banner image with different items (products the company offers); you can view the website site2.dvsport.com and see what i'm talking about. I would really like to make those cells with the product's names clickable areas that link to a page. Is this possible?

Thanks a ton.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/map

Comment: Have you tried googling for solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to make one image link to several pages, depending on where the image is clicked.

This technique is called imagemapping.

You simply specify which areas of the image should link to where.

In the example below, if you position the mouse in the upper left corner it links to yahoo .... and in the lower right corner.... it links to hotbot.

```
<img src="rainbow.gif" usemap = #example border=0> 
<map name=example>
<area shape=Rect Coords=0,0,29,29 Href="http://www.yahoo.com"> 
<area shape=Rect Coords=30,30,59,59 Href="http://www.hotbot.com"> 
</map>
```

In the above example we only used rectangular imagemappings. Possible shapes are:

```
<area shape=rect coords= x1,y1, x2,y2 Href="http://www.domain.com">


<area shape=circle coords= x1,y1, x2,y2 Href="http://www.domain.com">


<area shape=polygon coords= x1,y1, x2,y2, .., xn,yn Href="http://www.domain.com">
```

**Edit:**
Well for your genuine query you should have a look at this [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21375747/link-on-certain-position-of-an-image-background-which-is-responsive).

Comment: how responsive is this? if i developed on a 16:9 screen and the user was on 4:3 would it still work?

Comment: and how do i find the coordinates

Comment: For responsive web design check this tutorial https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_intro.asp